# How to change radius of fanmenu buttons?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am using FanMenu library for opening more buttons circularly from home button. But problem is I want to customize the size of all buttons but I am stuck in finding that particular code in framework files. Please guide me about this. Here is the link for example usage of [Fanmenu](https://github.com/exyte/fan-menu).

I have used FinanceViewController.swift file's fan menu option.

Comment: it looks like you have to adjust it by "menu_plus" and other images size

Comment: No. image sizes have nothing to do with it. Can you tell what is size of fanmenu button radius?Thank you so much in advance!